# Can i have clusters in the range of 500 to 2000, while building clustering of unsupervised classification

Tags: machine-learning, k-means

My dataset is of size 1,00,000 entries. Each entry gives me details of shirt size, shirt price and location. I want to classify this data by shirt brand.. from the source of data-set i know there are 500 different brands of shirts in dataset.

Can i use clustering algorithm with 500 clusters?. I plan to use K-Means is there any limitation on numbers of clusters, mostly i have seen examples of K-Means used for clustering say 5 to 10 clusters. I haven't see an example where number of clusters was 500.

Do you see K-Means is the best or i have to choose something else?.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your data, but generally speaking, k-means works for "medium" sized number of clusters (5-25 maybe).

See [scikit-learns' documentation page on clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#overview-of-clustering-methods), it contains a simple table comparing some clustering methods.
According to it, you should try "Ward hierarchical clustering", "Agglomerative clustering", or "Birch" instead of k-means.